# Is there an official driver for usb joystick?

Tags: drivers, joystick

I bought a USB Joystick years ago.

[image: USB Joystick]

But I've lost the disc driver comes with the USB Joystick. Fortunately, Windows 8.1 supports USB Joystick (it automatically download the driver from Microsoft) 
[image: USB Joystick driver]
but the problem is this driver won't support force feedback.

So my priority is making this Microsoft's default USB joystick driver work with force feedback. [A guy said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck-OSKt9G-k&lc=UgjG-Pb8FM1Cu3gCoAEC)

> VIBRATION FOR WINDOWS 10 Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10, it is working…! Just make a backup of the joy.cpl file located in the System32 folder, then DELETE the original (because Windows 8 won’t always allow you to REPLACE an existing file in that folder for some reason.) If you can’t delete it, change permissions (Remember Google is your best friend). Then copy (NOT move) the joy.cpl file from the SysWOW64 folder into the System32 folder﻿

But I don't know if there is a better way, messing with system32 is the last thing I'll do.

If it can't, then is there an official driver for usb joystick to make the force feedback work?